# Data not displaying in columns when export to excel using PHP and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server-2012, sqlsrv

I'm trying to export data in excel based on user selected column from checkboxes however the column name gets combined in one cell instead of storing in columns. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue? Below are my code and my error output

Current output which is wrong:
[image]

html

```
<form action="" id="colfilter"> 

    <input type="checkbox" name="column[]" class="column" value="[Column1]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="column[]" class="column" value="[Column2]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="column[]" class="column" value="[Column3]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="column[]" class="column" value="[Column4]">
    <a href="#" id="export">Download Full Data</a>

</form>
```

jquery

```
/*******export to excel*********/
            $('#export').click(function(){
                var colarray = [];
                var exportdata = 'true';

                $(".column").each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":checked"))
                    {
                        colarray.push($(this).val());
                    }   
                }); 

                colarray = colarray.toString();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "exportxls_file.php",
                    method:"GET",
                    data: {exportdata:exportdata, colarray:colarray},
                    success: function(){
                         window.open(this.url,'_blank' );
                    }
                });             


            });
```

exportxls_file.php

```
if($_GET['exportdata'] == 'true'){

        $colarray = $_GET['colarray'];

        /***Replace [ and ] with open and close single quote******/
        $string1 = ['[',']'];
        $string2 = ["'","'"];
        $newcolarray = str_replace($string1, $string2, $colarray);

    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = date('d-M-y') . ".csv"; // Create file name

    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    $fields = array($newcolarray);

    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);

 }
```

Comment: Can you change value from `[Column1]` to `Column1`?

Comment: I need the closing and opening square bracket for the column name as it is used for my SELECT statement query. Currently there's no issue with that so i omit that code out.

Comment: Let post data output in csv.

Comment: @AuNguyen nope i can't use post as I'm using a href to trigger the download

Comment: This is default Excel behaviour when opening CSV files, use "import" not "open".

Comment: after you download csv file, you could open it with editor application (example: notepad). And post data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might just be an issue with excel not using the right sperator - you can define the seperator by adding

```
"sep=,"
```

to the first line of your csv file.

you can do this by adding

```
fwrite($f, 'sep=,');
```

right after your `$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');`

Comment: if this doesnt work, please open your csv with your code editor and send us a screenshot of the csv structure :D

Comment: Nope. it return this error msg "fputcsv(): delimiter must be a single character ..."

Comment: no i mean like add it to the file after you made the csv

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you mentioned you want to export the data in Excel file but you are exporting the data in CSV Format, "CSV format is a plain text format in which values are separated by commas (Comma Separated Values), it doesn't display the data in columns, Either you can use PHPEXcellibrary to export the data as Excel or here are some code references which worked for me(Which you can customize as per your need)-

[Exporting data into Excel using PHP](https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-excel-in-php/)

[Exporting data into excel](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/)

If you want to use PHPExcel, here's the link for code reference:

[Exporting data using PHPExcel](https://learncodeweb.com/php/export-an-excel-file-with-phpexcel/)

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If i add a fixed array like this, the column name fit perfectly in each column cell but i need the array to be dynamic which the array is being treated as string.

```
$fields = array('column1',
                'column2',
                'column3',
                'column4');
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve it myself. My array was treated as string which is why my data was insert in one cell instead of a series of cell. I rewrote my code and included explode to convert my string into array. Below is my working code:

```
$colarray = $_GET['colarray'];

$string1 = ['[',']'];

$string2 = ["",""];

$newcolarray = str_replace($string1, $string2, $colarray);

$newarray = explode(",",$newcolarray);

$filename = date('d-M-y') . ".csv"; // Create file name

$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

fputcsv($f, $newarray);

$query = "SELECT "; 
$query .= $colarray;

$query .= " FROM OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL"; // Get data from Database from demo table
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    fputcsv($f, $row);

}
```